# What is the use of the 'data-toggle="collapse" button' in Bootstrap Navbar?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, navbar

I'm currently studying Bootstrap 4 and was looking into the Navbar part and had a question come up

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

The aboce is an example of all the sub-components included in a responsive light-themed navbar that automatically collapses at the lg (large) breakpoint.
However, I couldn't figure out the following part:

```
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
```

I know what the data-toggle is... but why does there specifically have to be a button type inside this html template? Couldn't you just input the `data-toggle` part into the `<div>` class right underneath the button class? Because I've seen in the document in the part of `nav > using dropdowns` that you can use the data-toggle inside the `<li>` element or the `<a>` element.

What is the purpose of this button?? I can't even see the button in the html when I open the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how your `Navbar` looks on regular basis.

[image: Regular State]

But when your screen starts shrinking, the contents have to go somewhere in order to fit, so it transforms into this:

[image: Shrunk state]

On the top right you see a button. That is exactly what you were asking about. This button, when pressed reveals all the navbar contents.

So basically, it is a button that allows this more responsive behavior while keeping all content available in some way.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you look at: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/? to get what I mean. But basically, when you run this code that you have posted, what you see is a Navbar that you can collapse, and it states 'Navbar' very clearly. Next to the word 'Navbar', there is a button which upon being pressed or clicked, presents to you the rest of the options that you have in the code like 'Home', 'Link', etc. So basically, this button you have said, when you click on it, you see the rest of the items that are supposed to be in the Navbar.

Now about why you are not seeing it, please minimize your screen and have a look at it. When the screen is smaller, the button appears with the 'Navbar-toggle-icon' that is mentioned in the button code below so that when you click on it you will see the other elements of the Navbar, which, on a bigger screen are displayed straightaway without the need of a button.

```
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

According to me you just have to make a simple HTML page. Add the bootstrap CDN link and notice how it work you can try once by removing the button and replace with its div.

You will get the exact idea of what exactly going on.
And You told that you didn't get any button over there, this button will display on the small size of the screen if you want to see this button you may decrease the size your browser.
You can also refer to this one  https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/